# How to use variables tag from Django in HTML ids

Tags: python, html, django, variables

My issue is actually quite simple and I'm not sure that there is an answer to it but still. I'm trying to reduce some image rendering that is hardcoded into my HTML template by making a simple for loop that Django provides with a dict comprehension. Actually everything is working in my project even if the "id" is not equal to the value "for" of my label. Here are my code and a screenshot of it. In the screenshot, you can clearly see that the id ignore the tag.

```
     <div class="form-check">

     {% for data in images %}
     <input class="form-check-input invisible" type="radio" name="image" id="{{ data }}" value="media/{{ data }}" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"><label class="form-check-label" for="{{ data }}">
           <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="media/{{ data }}" width="120" height="120">
        </label></button>
     {% endfor %}
```

```
     <input class="form-check-input invisible" type="radio" name="image" id="Profil1.png" value='media/Profil1.png' >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"><label class="form-check-label" for="Profil1.png">
           <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ "media/Profil1.png" }}" width="120" height="120">
        </label></button>
     <input class="form-check-input invisible" type="radio" name="image" id="Profil2.png" value='media/Profil2.png' >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"><label class="form-check-label" for="Profil2.png">
           <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ "media/Profil2.png" }}" width="120" height="120">
        </label></button>
     <input class="form-check-input invisible" type="radio" name="image" id="Profil3.png" value='media/Profil3.png' >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"><label class="form-check-label" for="Profil3.png">
           <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ "media/Profil3.png" }}" width="120" height="120">
        </label></button>
     <input class="form-check-input invisible" type="radio" name="image" id="Profil4.png" value="media/Profil4.png">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"><label class="form-check-label" for="Profil4.png">
           <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ "media/Profil4.png" }}" width="120" height="120">
        </label></button>
     </div>
```

[Screenshot of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTMRh.jpg)

Comment: `images` is a dictionary? with the image name as the key? Also, the `id` and `for` attributes look like they are resolving to the same string?

Comment: Every label is linked to the input by their Id and the for taking the same value as the id. As I Said, my for statement is working and everything is working actually. Images is a dictionary containing path. So the twist is juste that the "id" in the html code won't allow me to use the Django variable tag. If you look the screenshot it's gonna make more sense to you I think.

Comment: Hmmm, well, I'm not sure I follow, the `id` and `for` seems to be matching. You're using `id="{{ data }}"` and `for="{{ data }}"` and then get `id="Profil1.png"` and `for="Profil1.png"`.   Are you having trouble with how the `src="{{ "media/Profil1.png" }}"` is resolving?

Comment: Hey sorry this problem looks confusing actually it's just that in my VisualStudioCode view, at the "id:{{ data }}" the {{ data }} part is not inlighted as a variables tag. It's all orange, not blue and orange. I think it's just a visual studio issue actually and that's all because everything is working...

Comment: I see. Yeah, that's very likely just an anomaly of your IDE.